# ios - cannot decrypt after encryption

Tags: ios, pdf, encryption, nsdata, presentviewcontroller

I'm having troubles decrypting pdf files and displaying them with `presentViewController` after they are encrypted.

When I download the pdf files, they are being encrypted like this:

```
 NSData *pdfData = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:filePathDocumetFolder];

                    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                    NSString *documents = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
                    NSString *docFolder = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Documents/%@", documentFilePath];
                    NSString *filePath = [documents stringByAppendingPathComponent:docFolder];


                    NSString *pdfName = [NSString stringWithString:filename ];
                    NSError *error;
                    NSData *encryptedPdf = [RNEncryptor encryptData:pdfData withSettings:kRNCryptorAES256Settings password:@"A_SECRET_PASSWORD" error:&error];
if(error){
                    NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
                }
                    NSLog(@"where?? FileTra%@", filePath);
                    [encryptedPdf writeToFile:[filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:pdfName] atomically:YES];
```

I know that this encryption above works, as when I browse the filesystem with iExplorer, I cannot open the files because they are protected.

In my DocumentHandle controller I'm trying to decrypt them so that they can be viewed:

```
NSDictionary* dict = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];

        NSString* urlStr = dict[@"url"];
        NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
        NSString* fileName = [url path];

        NSString* path = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent: fileName];

        NSData *dataEn = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:[path stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName]];
        NSLog(@"this to decrypt%@", [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName]);
        NSData *decryp = [RNDecryptor decryptData:dataEn withSettings:kRNCryptorAES256Settings password:@"A_SECRET_PASSWORD" error:nil];
        [decryp writeToURL:[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:path] atomically:YES];
        if(decryp){
            NSLog(@"decrypted");
        }else{
            NSLog(@" not decrypted");
        }



        weakSelf.fileUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:path];
```

For some reason, the pdf files are not being decrypted and I'm being presented with a blank file even thought I'm receiving NSLog as decrypted :(

Can anyone help me please? thank you

Comment: Encrypting is not Protecting, so you should be able to view the encrypted file anyway. Could the filesize of your encrypted file be zero? You have turned off error checking during encryption with `error:nil`. Can you turn it on?

Comment: I have enabled `errors` but not getting any errors and also after the encryption the files have correct file size. They are not zero.

Comment: I propose `NSError *error = nil;` at that place. Can you add the error check to the decrypt too?

Comment: I implemented your proposal, but still not getting any errors and the documents are blank. Do you think, the decryption should happen asynchronously?

Comment: Are you sure that the file-path are the same? You use `NSTemporaryDirectory`which adds a `/tmp`to the path when you load but you don`t use it when you save.